# How can I configure IntelliJ to work with Apache Royale

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-royale

I'm starting to set up a workspace in IntelliJ to work with Royale. I've managed to do the same in Visual Studio Code and also in Moonshine IDE. So far no luck in IntelliJ. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is related request for Apache Royale support on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189525

Comment: Great, I added a comment there to ask them to consider support. Is it possible to get Royale working in IntelliJ without this support? As a starting setup?

Comment: I found some old instructions for FlexJS (from before the project was renamed to Royale). It might help you get started, even if some of the info is probably out of date. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Using+FlexJS+with+IntelliJ+IDEA

Comment: Their last response to me was that support of specific technology in Intellij is based at some point on their popularity. We are too small to have such support ;) However you have Moonshine and VSCode with monthly releases :) Support their authors and you got those better and better :)

Comment: Actually Moonshine and Visual Studio Code (with AS3&MXML) works pretty good, and seems more light and fast to me. Anyway would be great to have some day IntelliJ support.

Comment: I would love to see proper support for Apache Royale in IntelliJ IDEA